# the build teamcity tracks unknown branches

Tags: teamcity

my build only follows the release branch. a month ago, the build started to run from the master and develop branches (without my participation). forcing the exception of master and develop didn't help.

I disabled the trigger, but the build still tries to start.

see the screenshot

[image: example of a problem]

[image: disabled the trigger]

Comment: I'm not sure this will fix the problem, but its worth trying. You could add `-:*` along with `+:release/*`

Comment: If builds still happen when trigger is off then something else triggers them. To make sure configuration is not watching _wrong branches_ check VCS settings and implement your filters there too.

Comment: @IvanStarostin вот это меня и смущает, что сборку запускает "что-то" ещё. как может происходить запуск без триггера?

Comment: A human hand can. Build log page contains information about how it was triggered: git, trigger, user name. ps Note this website is for communication in English only. There is "ru" subdomain for Russian.